# How to Split Defined Elements Of A Nested List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I am quite new to Python3 and the issue I am having is the following:

I have a nested list structure of strings:

```
lst = [['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'], 
       ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'],
       ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar']]
```

So what I essentially want to achieve is to take the element [1] of each nested list and split it to achieve another nest in the list for example:

```
lst = [['foo' , ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'],
       ['foo' , ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'],
       ['foo' , ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar']]
```

I used list comprehension to split this element but in its own separate list so in this case the original elements [0] and [2] from each list are missing:

```
split_lst = [lst[1].split('\n') for lst in split_list]
```

How can I split this element but retain it in the original list with all other elements?

Comment: I have posted my proposition, That exactely what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension has its own scope. You cannot use it to change elements of a list in place.

Instead, you can use a `for` loop:

```
lst = [['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'], 
       ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'],
       ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar']]

for item in lst:
    item[1] = item[1].split()

print(lst)

[['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'],
 ['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'],
 ['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar']]
```

However, if you wish to use a list comprehension, you will need to form a list of lists explicitly:

```
res = [[i, j.split(), k] for i, j, k in lst]
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks! I tried this originally but forgot to specify the element in the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you need, I use just list cmpr and map

```
[map(lambda x : list(x.split()) if y.index(x)==1 else x, y) for y in lst]
```

Inthis case the in put :

```
lst = [['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'], 
   ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar'],
   ['foo', 'bar foo bar', 'foo bar']]
```

and the output is :

```
[['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'], 
['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar'], 
['foo', ['bar', 'foo', 'bar'], 'foo bar']]
```